# unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in nginxconfig.io

Tags: nginx

I created a nginx configuration using [nginxconfig.io](https://nginxconfig.io/?0.domain=myawesomesite.net&0.redirect=false&0.php=false&0.proxy&0.root=false&0.access_log_domain&0.error_log_domain).

I run nginx using docker (`FROM nginx:latest`).

When I run nginx I got the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myawesomesite.net.conf:1
```

After I review the files, I can't find any idea why I got this error. everything is format as well.

How I fix this problem?

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
# Generated by nginxconfig.io
# https://nginxconfig.io/?0.domain=myawesomesite.net&0.redirect=false&0.php=false&0.proxy&0.root=false&0.access_log_domain&0.error_log_domain

user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    log_not_found off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    # MIME
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    # Mozilla Intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout 2s;

    # load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/general.conf**

```
# favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# gzip
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myawesomesite.net.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name myawesomesite.net;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myawesomesite.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myawesomesite.net/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myawesomesite.net/chain.pem;

    # security
    include nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myawesomesite.net.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myawesomesite.net.error.log warn;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name myawesomesite.net;

    include nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://myawesomesite.net$request_uri;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf**

```
# ACME-challenge
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/_letsencrypt;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/security.conf**

```
# security headers
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

# . files
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf**

```
proxy_http_version  1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;

proxy_set_header Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection         "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host               $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
```

Comment: The error relates to a file in `sites-enabled` and the file you provide is from `sites-available`. Are these two files the same?

Comment: Not exactly, if I download the zip file I have sites-enabled folder inside I have file which contains: `../sites-available/myawesomesite.net.conf`

Comment: Do you mean a symlink or does it literally contain that text?

Comment: literally contain that text. try to download the file yourself. in the link in my question. you see

Comment: Usually `sites-enabled` contains a symlink to the files in `sites-available`. I don't know why your methodology has created the wrong file type. You could try `ln -s  ../sites-available/myawesomesite.net.conf` from within the `sites-enabled` directory.